# Iterate through levels of different factors by means of regression

Tags: regression

I am a newbie in R programming. I think for most of you my question is a rather simple one. My regression problem is as follows:

I have a dataframe containing several numerical attributes and several factors, which are different in the number of levels. I split the dataset in a training set and a test set. I will use the test set to calculate the prediction error of the regression. I want to iterate through the regression equation as follows:

1) I want to estimate a separate regression for the first level of the first factor using the trainings data and calculate the root mean square error for the prediction using the test set.

2) Then I want to repeat it for the second level of the first factor and so on until I have done it for each level of the first factor. Finally, calculate the total prediction error for the first factor.

3) Change the factor (now having another amount of levels, eg factor 2) and repeat the steps above.

I struggle with the two for-loops. The example juste iterates through different factors but not through each level. Please, see below for a toy example.

I appreciate every hint and thanks in advance!
Kind regards 
Marco

---- R code ----

```
    library(spdep)
    data(columbus)

    # create classes
    columbus$class1 <- as.factor(ifelse(columbus$CRIME < 30, 1 , 2))
    columbus$class2 <- as.factor(ifelse(columbus$CRIME < 20, 1 ,
      ifelse(columbus$CRIME >= 20 & columbus$CRIME < 40 , 2, 3)))
    columbus$class3 <- as.factor(ifelse(columbus$CRIME < 10, 1 ,
      ifelse(columbus$CRIME >= 10 & columbus$CRIME < 20 , 2, 
      ifelse(columbus$CRIME >= 20 & columbus$CRIME < 30, 3, 5))))
    # split test and trainings data  
    samp <- sample(nrow(columbus), size=35)
    train <- columbus[samp, ]
    test <- columbus[-samp, ]

    # regression just iterate through factors
    cllist <- paste("class", 1:3, sep="")  
    rmse_out <- vector()
    mod <- list()

    for (i in cllist) {
       nam <- c("INC", "HOVAL")
       fmla <- as.formula(paste("CRIME ~ ", paste(nam, collapse= "+"), "+", 
          as.name(i), "+", paste(nam, as.name(i), sep=":", collapse= "+")))
       mod[[i]] <- step(lm(fmla, data = train), trace=0)
       modsum <- summary(mod[[i]])
       print(modsum)
       rmse_out[i] <- sqrt(mean((test$CRIME - predict(mod[[i]], test, se.fit = TRUE)$fit)^2))
    }
```

Comment: When you say that you want to do the regression for the first level of the factor, what exactly do you mean? It seems that you mean that you want to use the subset of the data, but then it does not make sense to include the factor in the formula.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Yes, you are completely right. First pick the first subset of data which corresponds to the first level of factor one, then use the second level etc. If no more levels of the first factor are left, use the second factor and repeat it. Can I solve my iteration by means of two for loops? I ask your indulgence if it is nonsense.

Comment: Well, it can be done, but I doubt that you really want this. Are you familiar with the concept of dummy coding? What is your goal with this?

Answer (score 2):

There is a problem with what you want, since

```
unique(train[,c("class1","class2")])
```

gives

```
>    class1 class2
1046      1      1
1009      2      3
1029      2      2
1015      1      2
```

when we have

```
> levels(train$class1)
[1] "1" "2"
> levels(train$class2)
[1] "1" "2" "3"
```

This means that combination of `class1` being 2 and `class2` being 1 does not exist in your data. This will give you problems if you will do a thorough loop exhausting all the possibilities.

Since you want to do subseting, the only thing what matters for your calculation is the given data set. So I suggest to write a function which calculates what you want given the data you need. So in this case the function might look something like this:

```
myfun <- function(data) {
      step(lm(CRIME~INC+HOVAL, data = data), trace=0)
}
```

Then iterate it through all the factors:

```
fcomb <- unique(train[,c("class1","class2")])

mod <- list()
for(i in  1:nrow(fcomb)) {
    mod <- c(mod,list(myfun(subset(train,class1==fcomb$class1[i] & class2==fcomb$class2[i]))))
}
```

Now you can print the summaries like this:

```
lapply(mod,summary)
```

For calculating rmse again write special function:

```
myfun2 <- function(model) {
sqrt(mean((test$CRIME - predict(model, test, se.fit = TRUE)$fit)^2))
}
```

and then use it:

```
> sapply(mod,myfun2)
[1] 20.32188 28.49079 15.41444 22.50919
```

Writing individual functions is usually preferable, since this way it is easier to test them, or add additional features.

You can save yourself writing with using `dlply` from package **plyr**:

```
library(plyr)
mod<-dlply(train,~class1+class2,myfun)
```

This way you will even get legible names of the list elements, and changing the factors then will be trivial:

```
> sapply(mod,myfun2)
     1.1      1.2      2.2      2.3 
20.32188 22.50919 15.41444 28.49079
```

Note that the results are the same as before. Now with different factors:

```
> modo <- dlply(train,~class1+class3,myfun)
> 
> sapply(modo,myfun2)
     1.2      1.3      2.5 
20.32188 22.50919 21.13258
```

**Update** It turns out the subsetting should be done with only one factor. It is not hard to adapt the code for that case. I will update only the part with the `dlply`. This will work for one factor:

```
mod1 <- dlply(train,"class1",myfun)
lapply(mod1,summary)
rmse1 <- sapply(mod1,myfun2)
```

If we want to have everything in one object we can do:

```
modall <- lapply(cllist, function(cl) dlply(train,cl,myfun))
lapply(modall, function(l) lapply(l,summary))
lapply(modall, function(l) sapply(l,myfun2))
```

Comment: you misunderstood me, I am not interested in different combinations like class1 and class2. I want to use exclusively one of them. Sorry, if my posting was not clear enough!

Comment: Dear mpiktas, thanks a lot, I hope I can figure it out now with your help! Best m